# search box in select2 tool is showing up even there are no options to display?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I have used the select2 tool in my application, it is working fine when there are enough options to display. I have a condition where sometimes the options might be empty, at that time, I need to throw an alert text or warning instead of showing the blank select2 search box?

Is there a way to do so, I tried hiding the search box and disabling it but still the empty search box is being displayed there.

**html**

```
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" id="FirstSelect" name="firstselectbox" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

**.js file**

```
if (options.length == 0) {
          $("#alerttext").text("No options to display");
          $("#FirstSelect").prop("disabled", true);
          $('#FirstSelect').hide();
          $("#FirstSelect").select2({
            minimumResultsForSearch: -1
          });
}
```

Comment: Isn't the JavaScript code you have provided not working? I think it should work. If not then hide the container of the select and also when option is empty then don't call the select2 function.

Comment: No the javascript snippet is not working, okay I'll try the way you mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following code this should work for you.

```
var select2 = $("#FirstSelect").select2();
var listValue = $("#FirstSelect")[0].length;

if (listValue == 0) {
    select2.onSelect = (function(fn) {
        $(".select2-search").hide();
    })(select2.onSelect);
}
```

Check Out this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/summitpattel/pen/jQvjKO)